# Python error for Linked List append function

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, jupyter

I am trying to learn linked list implementation with python3. My code is throwing error "TypeError: Node() takes no arguments" when I am calling the append function .

```
class Node:
    def _init_(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.next=None
class LinkedList:
    def _init_(self):
        self.head=None

    def print_list(self):
        cur_node=self.head
        while cur_node:
            print(cur_node.data)
            cur_node=cur_node.next

    def append(self,data):
        new_node=Node(data)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
            return
        last_node = self.head
        while last_node.next:
            last_node=last_node.next
        last_node.next=new_node


llist = LinkedList()
llist.append('A')
llist.append('B')
```

The error with the above code is

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-893f725212cd> in <module>
      1 llist = LinkedList()
----> 2 llist.append('A')
      3 llist.append('B')

<ipython-input-3-a7f4eb6e69c9> in append(self, data)
     14 
     15     def append(self,data):
---> 16         new_node=Node(data)
     17         if self.head is None:
     18             self.head = new_node

TypeError: Node() takes no arguments
```

My full code is written above. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: It should be __init__(self,data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
def __init__(self,data):
```

2 underscores on each side of init

Comment: @sayakchowdhury so can you please mark it as correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

The error in the code is not saying that Node() isn't taking any arguments, but is trying to explain that Node() should not be taking any arguments when it is being initialized.

I don't know much about Node itself, but looking at the error, this is what I conclude.

This is due to the fact that you have made a simple syntax error when making the `__init__` function. You have one underscore around `_init_`, whereas it should be `__init__` with 2 underscores.

Comment: Thanks...you are correct. Your suggestion solved the problem.